# PHP: Allow only one login per user

Tags: php, session, authentication

Currently, I try to implement that only one user can be online simultaneously on the same account. There are solutions which prefer to store the session id and compare it to the current session id. But I have problems to understand how it should work.

So I store the session id after the user's login was successful. Now I am trying on another client to log in on the same account. It is not possible because the current session id is not equal to the stored id. So what happens if ...

1) Using logout button

The user uses the logout button. The session is destroyed. I reset the stored session id to `""` or something. If the stored session id is `""` a client can log in on this account. Is it right?

2) The browser is closed

Closing the browser without using the logout function. There is still a session id stored. I can not log in with this account because my current session id is not equal to the stored session id. So how can I realize a re-login?

Comment: case 2 you can use cookie as session storage. when you close browser cookie will be automatically destroyed (logout).

Comment: Store a session ID when the user signs in and verify the the client token (that was generated and stored in `$_SESSION`) with the stored token (table called `user_session`, with the column of the `user_id` and the `token`). Everytime the user signs in update the token so you don't need to worry about the sign out aspect (the last token has been overwritten therefore it is no longer valid so they will be booted out).

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can solve that problem simply by storing a variable in a user field database to indicate it's been logged in.

Comment: Because there are just a few users I don't use a database. I am storing username and hashed passwords with a .json. I could add a log in indicator but the problem is to reset it when the browser is closed. So some clients (several client computer) have access to my application and if on client A account A is online, client B should not be able to login with account A.

Comment: Oh ok, well what about before logging out, can you alter the login indicator found in the json and proceeds with logging out functionality.

Comment: It would be possible but case 2 would be still a problem because the indicator wouldn't be resetted when closing the browser.

Comment: @michaelT, if the json changes overtime it’s better to have it in sql in order to be consistent and easy to alter from the client side! Also, u will have a lot of capability with what you can do with mysql. Cheers!